# How to turn off scientific notation for the pandas.plotting.scatter_matrix method

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-science, visualization

I am trying to create a scatter matrix of a dataframe using the `pandas.plotting.scatter_matrix` method. It mostly works, but the automatic scientific notation is ruining my graph.

Here is the code and produced graph:

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(16,16))
pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(Df, hist_kwds= {'bins': 50} , alpha = 0.5, s = 10, diagonal = 'kde')
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y')
plt.show()
```

[Scatter Matrix, notice the '1e9' ruining the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dcPQ.png)

The third line of the provided code usually turns off the automatically formatted scientific notation while using `matplotlib.pyplot`, but doesn't work with this method. Does anyone know a way to do it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please try adapting the following code to yours. Basically you need to apply

```
ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='x')
```

and

```
ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y')
```

to each axes:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


# Create figure and plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# Set figure size
fig.set_size_inches(16, 16)

df = pd.DataFrame(2000000 * np.random.randn(1000, 4))
axS=pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(df, hist_kwds= {'bins': 50} , 
                           ax=ax, alpha = 0.5, s = 10, diagonal = 'kde')
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):
        axS[i,j].ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='x')
        if i != j:
             axS[i,j].ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y')
plt.show()
```